# How to force symfony's phpunit bridge to use phpunit 6.5 instead of 5.7?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, composer-php, version, bridge

## Problem

I'm using `Symfony 3.3.10` on `PHP 7.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`

By default this combination goes with `phpunit 5.x`.

But I want to force `phpunit 6.x`.

## Context

When I invoke the `vendor/bin/simple-phpunit` for the first time, it installs `phpunit/phpunit` version `5.7.*` as stated in the source code here:

https://github.com/symfony/phpunit-bridge/blob/v3.4.11/bin/simple-phpunit

lines 18-27:

```
if (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 70200) {
    // PHPUnit 6 is required for PHP 7.2+
    $PHPUNIT_VERSION = getenv('SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION') ?: '6.5';
} elseif (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600) {
    // PHPUnit 4 does not support PHP 7
    $PHPUNIT_VERSION = getenv('SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION') ?: '5.7';
} else {
    // PHPUnit 5.1 requires PHP 5.6+
    $PHPUNIT_VERSION = '4.8';
}
```

As my version of PHP is `7.0` it chooses phpunit version `5.7`.

## Tried solution

I see I may "force" the bridge to go with phpunit `6.5` if I set it in the environment variable:

In a shell, I do:

```
rm -Rf vendor
export SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION=6.5
composer install
vendor/bin/simple-phpunit
```

Now I properly get: `PHPUnit 6.5.8`

Instead, if I logout and login again, it looses the env-var and the next invocation to `vendor/bin/simple-phpunit` and it forces to install a 5.7.

## Don't tell me to put in the .bashrc

I already know I could set the env-var into my bash scripts and blah, blah, blah, but this is not an acceptable solution for two reasons:

1. I maintain over 50 repositories. Having this set always in all shells might cause side-effects on other projects.
2. If I make another developer to work on this repo, he should be able to do `git clone` + `composer install` + `vendor/bin/simple-phpunit` and it should be properly testing with no extra, manual, steps.

## Question

Is it possible to tell the project (maybe something in the `composer.json`) to have some fancy setup so symfony's phpunit bridge is forced to use `phpunit 6.x` (for example `6.5`) over the `5.7` version for **all** installs of the repo and **not** depending on anything global external to the repo?

Answer (score 6):

Since version 4.1 you can configure this in `phpunit.xml`/`phpunit.xml.dist`:

```
<php>
    <env name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="6.5" />
</php>
```

Comment: version 4.1 of symfony? or version 4.1 of phpuunit itself?

Comment: Version 4.1 of `symfony/phpunit-bridge` - https://github.com/symfony/phpunit-bridge/blob/v4.1.0/CHANGELOG.md#410

Comment: Ah ok... I see. I'm currenly requiring `"symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"` in my composer. If I upgrade the major, are there any risks to break all? I mean... is bridge 3 thought for symfony 3 and bridge 4 thought for symfony 4? Or symfony 3 may run safely with bridge 4 without expecting too much to break?

Comment: I have no idea about BC breaks, but Symfony 3.4.10 has `symfony/phpunit-bridge: ~3.4|~4.0` in their `require-dev`, so I guess it should work fine. https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony#v3.4.10

Comment: I use `bin/phpunit` which is installed by `symfony/phpunit-bridge: 4.2.4`. I tried your method to set the phpunit version to 7.5, but it doesn't work. The only working way is to set the version in `bin/phpunit` on the line `putenv('SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION=7.5')`. Do you know why is it like that?